# Fabric not accepting @string/... reference for its API key in manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to hide my fabric API key from source control by putting the key in an un-tracked string resource XML file. But for some reason, fabric is not accepting the key vie `@string/FABRIC_API_KEY` reference in the manifest.

The XML file is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="NASA_API_KEY">abcd</string>
    <string name="FABRIC_API_KEY">xyz</string>
</resources>
```

The reference in the manifest -

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:text="@string/FABRIC_API_KEY" />
```

And, here is the error I get on an attempt to build -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

I have tried accessing the API key via `BuildConfig` and it still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Fabric,

You should stop adding this key field in AndroidManifest.xml. Instead you should add it in fabric.properties.

Basically fabric library will automatically merge this  key later in your merged AndroidManifest.xml.

REF : https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#android-projects

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made `fabric.properties` file in the root directory and added the API key the way they mentioned it. But, I still get the same error.

Comment: It worked for me... I placed fabric.properties on module root, at the same level as progruard-rules.pro or  build.gradle, for example) but I added on it both secretKey and apiKey.
As they told me at support@fabric.io, "You can find your secret key here: https://fabric.io/settings/organizations  after selecting your Organization. Just select the "Build Secret" button under your organization's name."

Comment: For me the fabric.properties method of specifying the keys only worked after disabling Instant Run on the project.

Answer (score 3):

In `build.gradle` add `manifestPlaceholders`:

```
defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        FABRIC_API_KEY:"Your Key"
    ]
}
```

Use it in `AndroidManifest.xml` like

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="${FABRIC_API_KEY}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay..I have got the answer by my own... here is the code,which helped me :

Follow this steps:-

https://github.com/plastiv/CrashlyticsDemo/

mostly people have to problem run the gradle command line so you can use like this: 1) Open terminal.

2) Go to your project work space

3) ./gradlew

(Note if permission denies error use this command- chmod 744 gradlew and again run ./gradlew)

(4) ./gradlew assemble -P apiKey=Your fabric api key

Now you can fully secret your api key but remember one thing your fabric.properties looks like that

fabric.properties:-

apiSecret=”Your fabric secret key” apiKey=”Your fabric api key”

Enjoy!

Comment: Also you can remove 

1) defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        FABRIC_API_KEY:"Your Key"
    ]
}

2) <meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="${FABRIC_API_KEY}"
/>